# Cannot set LC_ALL to locale en_US.UTF-8: JavaScript is not supported

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I'm running mysql `v8.0.23` in my local machine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
$ sudo snap install mysql-shell
```

But when I try to enter `mysqlsh` enter into js mode, It is giving the following error:

```sh
$ mysqlsh --js
Cannot set LC_ALL to locale en_US.UTF-8: No such file or directory
JavaScript is not supported.
```

Though I can switch to `\sql` or `\py`. What am I missing?

```
SHELL COMMANDS

The shell commands allow executing specific operations including updating the
shell configuration.

The following shell commands are available:

 - \                   Start multi-line input when in SQL mode.
 - \connect    (\c)    Connects the shell to a MySQL server and assigns the
                       global session.
 - \disconnect         Disconnects the global session.
 - \edit       (\e)    Launch a system editor to edit a command to be executed.
 - \exit               Exits the MySQL Shell, same as \quit.
 - \G                  Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
 - \g                  Send command to mysql server.
 - \help       (\?,\h) Prints help information about a specific topic.
 - \history            View and edit command line history.
 - \nopager            Disables the current pager.
 - \nowarnings (\w)    Don't show warnings after every statement.
 - \option             Allows working with the available shell options.
 - \pager      (\P)    Sets the current pager.
 - \py                 Switches to Python processing mode.
 - \quit       (\q)    Exits the MySQL Shell.
 - \reconnect          Reconnects the global session.
 - \rehash             Refresh the autocompletion cache.
 - \show               Executes the given report with provided options and
                       arguments.
 - \source     (\.)    Loads and executes a script from a file.
 - \sql                Executes SQL statement or switches to SQL processing
                       mode when no statement is given.
 - \status     (\s)    Print information about the current global session.
 - \system     (\!)    Execute a system shell command.
 - \use        (\u)    Sets the active schema.
 - \warnings   (\W)    Show warnings after every statement.
 - \watch              Executes the given report with provided options and
```

Comment: check below link which will help you to get it resolved
https://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: tried didn't help

Answer (score 0):

tried to follow the offical documentation again..

needed to add apt-package for mysql

everything working fine now.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-linux-quick.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-setup